# List mounted TrueCrypt Volumes to stdout via the command line?

Tags: command-line, stdout, truecrypt

Does anyone know a way to list mounted TrueCrypt volumes to stdout via the command line?

The page below suggests the --list option would do it in the *nix version, but I can't find any way to do this with Windows.

http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=backtrack-3-man/truecrypt

Answer (score 0):

I faced with same question and found solution, use forward slash symbol. Example [here](https://superuser.com/questions/502552/truecrypt-drive-letter-not-available)

In addition use "/help" key.
Hope this helps you.